# Most efficient way to read a huge parquet file into memory in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, parquet, pyarrow

Ideally, I would like to have the data in a dictionary. I am not even sure if a dictionary is better than a dataframe in this context. After a bit of research, I found the following ways to read a parquet file into memory:

- Pyarrow (Python API of Apache Arrow):

With pyarrow, I can read a parquet file into a pyarrow.Table. I can also read the data into a pyarrow.DictionaryArray. Both are easily convertible into a dataframe, but wouldn't memory consumption double in this case?

- Pandas:

Via pd.read_parquet. The file is read into a dataframe. Again, would a dataframe perform as well as a dictionary?

- parquet-python (pure python, supports read-only):

Supports reading in each row in a parquet as a dictionary. That means I'd have to merge *a lot* of nano-dictionaries. I am not sure if this is wise.